# Como acessar os dados do HttpErrorResponse (error.Mensagem) pelo Angular 2 (7)?

Tags: angular, component

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código Component.ts

```
delete(i: number) {
    this.formConcluido = false;
    this.formConcluidoErro = false;
    this.cidadeDeletar = this.cidades[i];
    this.cidadeDeletarId = this.cidadeDeletar.Id;
    this.cadastroCidadeService
      .DeleteCidade(this.cidadeDeletarId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log('success', res);
        this.resposta = "Cidade Deletada com Sucesso";
        this.formConcluido = true;
        this.ngOnInit();
      },
        error => {
          console.log('error', error);
          this.resp = error.Mensagem;
          this.formConcluidoErro = true;
          console.log(error.Mensagem);
        });
  }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
error => {
          console.log('error', error);
          this.resp = error.Mensagem;
          this.formConcluidoErro = true;
          console.log(error.Mensagem);
        });
```

**console.log(error.Mensagem);** (está vindo - undefined)

**console.log('error', error);** (está vindo com os valores.)

Como consigo acessar o campo Mensagem, para retornar ao usuário.?

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------  */

**RESPOSTA:**

```
error => {
          console.log('error', error);
          this.resp = error.error.Mensagem;
          this.formConcluidoErro = true;
          console.log(error.Mensagem);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a variável **error** do "console.log('error', **error**);" é um objeto, então existe varios outros objetos dentro da variável **error**.

sendo assim se voce acessar **error**.error voce conseque acessar os objetos que vem dentro desta variável.

se voce acessar a variável **error**.error.Messagem voce terá a string que está dentro.